# How to add boundaries for the points of a ListPlot?

Tags: plotting, graphics, style, plot-themes

I have a plot as below:

```
ListPlot[{{{1, 5}}, {{4, 2}}}, PlotStyle -> {{Red, PointSize[0.03]}, {Green, PointSize[0.03]}}, PlotRange -> {{0, 5}, {0, 6}}]
```

[image]

I want to add black circular boundaries for the red and green spots. What can I do?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ListPlot[{{{1, 5}}, {{4, 2}}}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Red, Green}, 
 PlotRange -> {{0, 5}, {0, 6}}, 
 PlotMarkers -> {Graphics[{EdgeForm[Black], Disk[]}], .1}]
```

[image]

```
BubbleChart[{{1, 5, .3}, {4, 2, .3}}, ChartStyle -> {Red, Green}, 
 PlotRange -> {{0, 5}, {0, 6}}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Is it possible to add black at the boundary only instead of adding black at the back? What I want to do is to use `Opacity[0], Red` instead of just `Red` to make it transparent, and then add the spots to another plot. So if the black is at the back, there will be no transparency.

Comment: @H42,  with  `EdgeForm[Black]` only the edge of the disk is painted black, not the whole disk.

Comment: Oh sorry I mixed up the codes. many thanks!